# ActivityResultHandler sometimes not working

Tags: gluon-mobile

Im using a slightly modified version of the Gluon `AndroidPicturesService` (to be able to access the taken / selected picture). While taking or selecting a picture is basically working, sometimes there is no activity result and the app gets new initialized, i.e. there is no `FXActivity onRestart` prior to `onStart, onResume`, or even worse there is a crash (it seems not to be caused by a specific image or directory).

```
public class AndroidPictureService {

    private static final int      TAKE_PICTURE   = 1;
    private static final int      SELECT_PICTURE = 2;

    private File                  imageFile;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> image;

    public AndroidPictureService() {
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        if (image == null) {
            image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        return image;
    }


    public void takePicture(int width, int height, boolean savePicture) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File sourceFile = createImageFile();
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(sourceFile);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((requestCode, resultCode, data) ->
        {
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(FXActivity.getInstance(), new String[] { sourceFile.toString() }, null, null);

                    if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                        File tmpFile = new File(FXActivity.getInstance().getFilesDir(), "image_tmp.jpg");
                        adjustSizeAndStoreImage(sourceFile, tmpFile, width, height);
                        imageFile = tmpFile;
                    } else {
                        imageFile = sourceFile;
                    }

                    image.set(new Image(Uri.fromFile(imageFile).toString()));

                    if (!savePicture) {
                        sourceFile.delete();
                    }
                }
                Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    try {
                        Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(imageProperty(), null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("GalleryActivity: exitNestedEventLoop failed: " + e);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        if (intent.resolveActivity(FXActivity.getInstance().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            FXActivity.getInstance().startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            try {
                Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(imageProperty());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("GalleryActivity: enterNestedEventLoop failed: " + e);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("GalleryActivity: resolveActivity failed");
        }
    }

    public void retrievePicture(int width, int height) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((requestCode, resultCode, data) ->
        {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                String selectedImagePath = FileUtils.getPath(FXActivity.getInstance(), selectedImageUri);
                if (selectedImagePath != null && !selectedImagePath.isEmpty()) {
                    File sourceFile = new File(selectedImagePath);

                    if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                        File tmpFile = new File(FXActivity.getInstance().getFilesDir(), "image_tmp.jpg");
                        adjustSizeAndStoreImage(sourceFile, tmpFile, width, height);
                        imageFile = tmpFile;
                    } else {
                        imageFile = sourceFile;
                    }

                    imageProperty().set(new Image(Uri.fromFile(imageFile).toString()));
                }

                Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    try {
                        Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(imageProperty(), null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("GalleryActivity: exitNestedEventLoop failed: " + e);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // check for permissions
        if (intent.resolveActivity(FXActivity.getInstance().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            FXActivity.getInstance().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            try {
                Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(imageProperty());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("GalleryActivity: enterNestedEventLoop failed: " + e);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("GalleryActivity: resolveActivity failed");
        }
    }

@Override
public void adjustSizeAndStoreImage(File sourceFile, File targetFile, int width, int height) {
    try (InputStream inForSizeCalculation = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            InputStream inForBitmapCreation = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inForSizeCalculation, null, options);

        int scale = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = scale;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inForBitmapCreation, null, options);

        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to adjustSizeAndStoreImage", ex);
    }
}  

    private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            while (halfHeight / inSampleSize >= reqHeight && halfWidth / inSampleSize >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private File createImageFile() {
        String timeStamp = DateTimeFormatters.createTimeStamp();
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
    }

}
```